# User prompt as they close the browser window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am finalising our company Google Sheet and completed all the app scripting.

We rely on clients submitting data to us using the function we have which is a simple email function. Is it possible to ask them "Have you finished adding your data?" with Yes, No buttons when they go to close their browser window? If yes it will run the function and prevent them forgetting!

window.onbeforeunload
or
google.script.host.close();

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

There is no onClose trigger that can achieve your target. See reference link to validate: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

So my suggestion for your case will be like this. First, create a button(example, name your button "Submit data to Admin") for the user(s) and ask them to press it after submitting the data. You can write a remark to remind them to press it after submitting the data. For example:
*Remark: Please press the button "Submit data to Admin" after you're done inputing the data.*

To create a button in your Google Sheet, follow the steps below:
(**Reference link:** https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-sheets-button/)

1. Go to Insert > Drawing menu. This brings up the drawing editor where you can easily add a box and style it to look like a button.
2. When you click Save and Close, this drawing gets added to your Google Sheet. You can click on it to resize it or drag it around to reposition it.
3. To assign a script, click the three little dots in the top right of the drawing and select Assign Script.
4. Then type in the name of the function you want to run from your Apps Script code.

**After pressing the button, it will do the following functionalities:**
(See this reference link for the detailed guide on how to do the alert box and its functionalities: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#:~:text=Scripts%20that%20are%20bound%20to,are%20opened%20from%20menu%20items.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#:%7E:text=Scripts%20that%20are%20bound%20to,are%20opened%20from%20menu%20items.))

1. Show the alert box/dialog.
2. If Yes, it will run your function.
3. It will also send an email to the admin as an email notification.

Comment: Thanks, Monique G. This was my thinking, however, I thought I would ask the pro's before I proceeded. I really appreciate your time and advice. Stay safe.